# ToggleClass jQuery for only ONE element of li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add a background color to a checkbox and its text after the user clicks on it (checking it). In here though, it adds in all of my list not only the LI clicked.

HTML

```
<li class="parent_category">
  <ul>
      <li class="behind">
              <label>
                  <input type="checkbox">
                  Text3 Text Text
              </label>
       </li>
       <li class="behind">
              <label>
                  <input type="checkbox">
                  Text2 Text Text
              </label>
       </li>
       <li class="behind">
              <label>
                  <input type="checkbox">
                  Text1 Text Text
              </label>
       </li>
       <li class="behind">
              <label>
                  <input type="checkbox">
                  Text4 Text Text
              </label>
       </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

jQuery

```
define([], function(){
  var main = function(data, options) {

    $(function () {
      $(".parent_category").click(function() {

        $(this).toggleClass("selected");
      });

      $("label.parent_category").click(function(e) {

        $(e.currentTarget).toggleClass("background");
      });
    });
    console.log("Select Recommended loaded");
  }
  return main;
});
```

And then the Sass file

```
.parent_category
float: right
margin: 15px
&.selected
  border: 4px solid #ffe400
  ul
      width: 100%
      padding: 0px
      li
          padding-left: 20px
          border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC
          display: block
          &:last-child
              border-bottom: none

.behind
display: none

.background
background-color: #CCCCCC
width: 100%
```

So what I'm trying to achieve is > I want the background of one li (the whole row) to go gray when the user ticks it, and to go back to its normal state when user unclicks it. Also, right now when I click on the tick my 'selected' class gets toggled making my li disappear and I don't want that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't get, why you add click event on this element $("label.parent_category")  - you don't have such in your html structure..  Is it a typo?

Try this variant:

```
$('.parent_category input:checkbox').on('change', function(){
        var $checkbox = $(this);
        $checkbox.closest('label').toggleClass('background', $checkbox.is(':checked'));
    });
```

instead of

```
$("label.parent_category").click(function(e) { $(e.currentTarget).toggleClass("background"); });
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thanks Denys! You can edit your answer above and I'll put it as the right one! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace :

```
$("label.parent_category").click(function(e) {
```

By :

```
$(".parent_category label").click(function(e) {
```

I think you made a mistake with your selector.

Comment: While this will technically work, it should be noted that it will add a click handler for every result of the `".parent_category label"` selector. So if you had 100 lables, it would add 100 click handlers. It is more efficient to use `$('.parent_category').on('click', 'label', function)` on the parent element with a selector to target the child elements, which would result in only 1 handler function being added to the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [.on function](http://api.jquery.com/on/) with a selector as the 2nd parameter:

```
$('.parent_category').on('click', 'li', function (clickEvent) {
    // ...
});
```

This will add 1 click handler to the DOM that reacts to each `li` in `.parent_category`.